# equivalence in category

Tags: category-theory, modules

First gives some definitions, and then the property that I am confused.

$A$, $B$ are both $R$-module, and $C$, $D$ an (additive) abelian group, consider the category $M(A,B)$ whose objects are all *middle linear* maps on $A\times B$.

Then by definition a morphism in $M(A,B)$ from $f:A\times B \rightarrow C$ to $g:A\times B \rightarrow D$ is a group homomorphism $h:C\rightarrow D$ with $g=h(f)$.

> Prop: $h$ is an **equivalence** in $M(A,B)$ if and only if $h$ is an isomorphism of groups.

I think $h$ only needs to be an "isomorphism" on "image of $f$" to "image of $g$" in order to be an equivalence. Since outside of it there is no restriction given by $f$ and $g$.

For example let $C=A \times B\times X$ and $D=A \times B\times X$ and let $f$ and $g$ be " forgetful inclusion" then $h$ can be arbitrary assign on $X$, hence may not be an isomorphism.

What am I missing?

Reference:
The Definitions of [middle linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) and the definition of equivalence.
[image: equivalence]

Comment: What's a "middle linear map on $A\times B$"?

Comment: @egreg It is defined in wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), It might be also called " balanced" or "bilinear(?)"<- not so sure.

Comment: OK; let me think about it; but “equivalence” should be “isomorphism”, I guess.

Comment: I have added some reference about the terminology!

Comment: Man, this is bothering me... your claim as presented is definitely wrong, simply because the identity in a category is unique. Thus if $\operatorname{id}\colon C\to C$ is an identity for $f\colon A\times B\to C$, a morphism $g\colon C\to C$, which acts as identity on the image of $f$ can't be an identity of $f$ as well, provided $M(A,B)$ as defined is indeed a category. I have a hard time finding a couterexample, though.

Comment: The "forgetful inclusion" maps aren't middle linear. For example, $f(a+a',b)=(a+a',b,0)$, but $f(a,b)+f(a',b)=(a+a',2b,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow find the solution myself.

The example I gave is just wrong, it is not middle linear. (Thanks to @Jeremy Rickard for noticing.)

And since the identity of morphism is unique (Thanks to @roman for a remind), $1_{f}$ must be the identity isomorphism on $C$. And similarly for $1_{g}$.

Hence for $h$ to be an equivalence, there must exist $h'$, such that $h'(h)=1_{f}=1_{C}$ and $h(h')=1_{g}=1_{D}$, hence $h$ is an isomorphism from $C$ to $D$.

Comment: Well, even though you're particular example was wrong, given $f\colon A\times B\to C$, you can still define maps $i_0\colon C\to C\times C, c\mapsto (c,0)$ and $\Delta\colon C\to C, c\mapsto (c,c)$. Then there are morphisms $a,b\colon C\times C\to C\times C$, which induce maps $a \colon i_0\circ f\to \Delta\circ f$ and $b\colon \Delta\circ f\to i_0\circ f$ and are isomorphisms on the images of $i\circ f$ and $\Delta\circ f$, but aren't group isomorphism. So to prove that $M(A,B)$ is indeed a category, you'd have to show that $a\circ b\ne \operatorname{id}_{\Delta\circ f}$